# Haproxy replace whitespace in request URL with %20, how?

Tags: haproxy

For example, I have header `GET /yo?title=What a cool day HTTP/1.1`
I want to replace whitespaces with `%20` `GET /yo?title=What%20a%20cool%20day HTTP/1.1`. I want replace because backends with nginx do not accept incorrect HTTP requests. It's a pity, but I don't have access to nginx to patch or to modify code generated this incorrect URLs.

I've tried using `reqrep` directive, but according haproxy docs it replaces whole `search` with `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442658/spaces-in-urls) post on StackOverflow, spaces in URLs aren't valid so whatever is generating these requests is flawed.

I also had a poke around the HAProxy docs and I don't see any way to do it.

Actually, if you know for certain that there's not going to be more than 8 spaces, I suppose you could use `reqrep` something like this:

```
reqrep ^GET\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)\ ([^\ \t]*)    GET\ \1%20\2%20\3%20\4%20\5%20\6%20\7%20\8%20\9%20\ HTTP/1.1
```

Though that doesn't account for URLs which have less than 8 spaces, so you'd either need to add `?`'s to each substring reference search (and the following space) or setup 8 `reqrep`'s to account for all the different permutations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was thinking about this solution, but it could totally ruine URLs containing more than 8 spaces and something after `title` query parameter. Anyway thank you for quick response!